# Secure remote debugging JBoss

Tags: security, jboss, remote-debugging

I got the following report:

[image: Vulnerability]

---

My Question is: How do I connect to the JVM without having this security Issue?

I thought about SSH Tunneling.

It looks like these opts are the problem:

```
JAVA_OPTS_EXTRA="$JAVA_OPTS_EXTRA -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=4077,server=y,suspend=n"
```

Can I just open the debug port for localhost only, where do I configure it?

Comment: Have you enabled debug for your jboss server?

Answer (score 0):

By Adding `JAVA_OPTS_EXTRA="$JAVA_OPTS_EXTRA -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=4077,server=y,suspend=n"`
in you jboss server script startup you are enabling the remote debug mode for the server. Just comment this line and restart the server so that you will not get this vulnerability.

To enable debug mode for shared-memory only (localhost debug mode), you have to use
`dt_shmem` instead of `dt_socket`. Check the following the links for more information.

For JBoss Debug configuration [JBoss AS7: Using JPDA to debug the AS source code](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/JBossAS7UsingJPDAToDebugTheASSourceCode)

[For Java remote debugging](https://stackify.com/java-remote-debugging/)

Comment: But I still want/need to debug. I'd like to have it enabled. But reject any remote address from accesing it

Comment: Ideally debug mode should be enabled for development environment not for other environment. So I would recommend you to use debug mode for dev environment and for higher environment disable it.

Comment: @0x45 Vulnerability report matters for higher environment only.

Comment: It runs automatically on the EC2 machine for every environment. And yes, I only got in enabled on my dev machine. Does JBoss/OPTS support anything regarding it, without completely disabling it?

Comment: By default debug mode is disabled for jboss. You have to add above options to enable it. May be JBoss installer copy provided to you have debug mode enabled already. Many times companies provide such kind of customized packages. If your jboss package have debug mode enabled then, I would recommend you to manually disable it for higher environment so that you will not get this vulnerability in your report

Comment: @0x45 I found a way to enable debug for localhost only. Updated answer